# How to install pygame in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with Anaconda Python 3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, installation

I want to install 'pygame' library in Ubuntu 14.04 with Anaconda Python 3.6 environment.

Anyone can do this?

I have tried these methods:

1. `conda install -c cogsci pygame`
2. `conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2`
3. `sudo apt-get install pygame`

Comment: And I also find this website, [CompileUbuntu](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu) but there is no condition for Anaconda

Comment: `pygame` is python module so first try `pip install pygame`

Comment: BTW: if you try to install something with `apt` then first check its full name `apt-cache search pygame` and you will see `python-pygame` (at least I have it on Linux Mint 18 based on Ubuntu 16.04). BTW: in newest Ubuntu you can use `apt` instead of `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. If you prefer GUI then use `aptitude` (text mode) or `synaptic` (graphics mode)

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted this website can help me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

I find this link, very nice.

**Pygame Installation**
Pygame requires Python; if you don't already have it, you can download it
 from python.org. Use python 3.6.1 or greater, because it is much friendlier to newbies, and additionally runs faster.

*Visit here to download pygame: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml*

**The best way to install pygame is with the pip tool** (which is what python uses to install packages). 
Note, this comes with python in recent versions. We use the `--user` flag to tell it to install into the home directory, rather than globally.

```
python3 -m pip install pygame --user
```

To see if it works, run one of the included examples:

```
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

If it works, you are ready to go! Continue on to the tutorials.